# Google Firebase alternative for IOS apps for kids

Tags: ios, firebase, analytics, privacy

We've been using Google FireBase for App Analytics and AB testing in our IOS kids apps.
A few months ago Apple started rejecting our apps because Google firebase is not compliant with Apple's privacy guidelines for kids games.

Flurry also doesn't comply with those guidelines (even the limited feature set).

So we removed analytics completely and we are flying blind sort of speak.

Before I tackle the task of building an in-house analytics and AB-testing tool I was wondering if maybe anyone knows of a platform that Apple accepts.

Thank you
Niro

Comment: Recommendations are considered off-topic on SO, however, you could try [Appwrite](https://appwrite.io), which is intended to be a replacement for Firebase that you can self-host, which will solve most privacy issues.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has an Analytics option to make iOS kids compliant Appstore compliant.

In CocoaPods, do `pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport'` (instead of `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`)

More documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios#disable-IDFA-collection